# how to use moment.js in IE 8

Tags: javascript, html, momentjs

In all the documentation for moment, you just use a variable called moment. In all browsers but IE 8 this works. In IE 8 it says

**The value of the property 'moment' is null or undefined, not a Function object**

This moment variable is in the very first line of the moment js file but how can I tell my browser to go into moment and find this????

I am parsing date from the past using this library.

Here is my script declaration for moment.js

```
<script src="https://raw.github.com/timrwood/moment/2.0.0/moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Regarding the variable being defined "in the very first line" of the file: the var moment you see in the first few lines only exists inside the immediate function (the anonymous function that encompasses the whole file and is called at the last line). Moment as a global variable is only added as one of the very last steps of this function: this['moment'] = moment;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably because you are trying to load it directly from GitHub, try downloading a local copy and linking to it with a relative link:

```
<script src="moment.js""></script>
```

I built a quick test page and it looks like if you try to load the script directly from GitHub they return a HTTP code `200 OK`, but the response is empty. Since the file it loads is empty, `moment` is indeed never defined.